# Wikipedia export api version

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

From time to time, Wikipedia Export Api changes its xml schema version:

Ex. request http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Apple
gives:

```
<mediawiki xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7.xsd" version="0.7" xml:lang="en">
```

Previously it has 0.6 version.

Is there a way to request specific xml schema version? Otherwise, it simply breaks my service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly breaks your service? What information do you want to get?

Comment: The schema probably changes when a new kind information is added to the database (such as the sha1 hash recently). That should not be a problem if you use a sane method of XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know, see also [Parameters to Special:Export](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_Special%3aExport) and [Help:Export](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aExport).

Might it be possible to parse the file dynamically according to the [schema](http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.7.xsd)? Or have you tried using the [query api](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery)?

Answer (score 1):

Special:Export is not an API, it's mostly intended for manual moves of data between wikis.

There's a proper API at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php which is documented [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page), you should use it for all automatic access.

Comment: Although special:export seems to be superior for some use cases. You e.g. can't download all revisions of a set of pages and the templates they use in one request via api.php.